# Entire function that is strictly increasing on the real line

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

**STATEMENT:** Let $f$ be an entire function which maps the real line into the real line and the upper half-plane into the upper half-plane. Prove that $f$ is strictly increasing on the real line.

**QUESTION:** I am unsure of how to proceed with this problem. Can someone please nudge me along the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $z = x+iy$ and $f(z) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$. Since $f$ is entire, we have
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}.$$
Namely, this equality holds on the real line:
$$\left. \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right|_{y = 0} = \left. \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right|_{y = 0}.$$
In order for $f$ to be strictly increasing on the real line, we want $\left. \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right|_{y = 0} > 0$ for all $x$. So, the question boils down to showing that $\left. \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right|_{y = 0} > 0$ for all $x$.